# Which algorithm I can use to find common adjacent words/ pattern recognition?

Tags: sql, algorithm, r, artificial-intelligence, pattern-recognition

I have a big table in my database with a lot of words from various texts in the text order. I want to find the number of times/frequency that some set of words appears together.

**Example**: Supposing I have this 4 words in many texts: `United | States | of | America`. I will get as result:

**United States**: 50
**United States of**: 45
**United States of America**: 40

(This is only an example with 4 words, but can there are with less and more than 4).

There is some algorithm that can do this or similar to this?

**Edit:** Some R or SQL code showing how to do is welcome. I need a practical example of what I need to do.

**Table Structure**

I have two tables: `Token` which haves `id` and `text`. The text is is `UNIQUE` and each entrance in this table represents a different word.

`TextBlockHasToken` is the table which keeps the text order. Each row represents a word in a text.

It haves `textblockid` that is the block of the text the token belongs. `sentence` that is the sentence of the token, `position` that is the token position inside the sentence and `tokenid` that is the token table reference.

Comment: can you please show your table estructure? plaese also explain how are the individual words sotred in the table, and how are they related to know that they are part of a text.

Comment: @LuisSiquot I updated my question with table structure.

Comment: Renato, how are the "some conjunctions of words" you want to find defined? By the tokens in the phrase or the number of times the phrase occurs or something else?

Comment: @JeffKubina Was an English mistake: "some set of words." By the type of the tokens, I want to find proper names and common expressions that only have meaning when used together.

Comment: Are you missing a result? (a result for United alone because there is a delimiter between United and States)

How big is your table?  And do you have the option to modify table attributes?  The simplest answer is to use unions in your query but honestly to give you a good answer, it would help to know how big "big" actually is at least in terms of records.  

By the way, is this for an association mining algorithm?  If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you should take a look at how lift is calculated and it may help you.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is called an N-gram; in your case a 4-gram. It can indeed be obtained as the by-product of a Markov-chain, but you could also use a sliding window (size 4) to walk through the (linear) text while updating a 4-dimensionsal "histogram".

UPDATE 2011-11-22:
A markov chain is a way to model the probability of switching to a new state, given the current state.  This is the stochastic equivalent of a "state machine".  In the natural language case, the "state" is formed by the "previous N words", which implies that you consider the prior probability (before the previous N words) as equal_to_one.  Computer people will most likely use a tree for implementing Markov chains in the NLP case.  The "state" is simply the path taken from the root to the current node, and the probabilities of the words_to_follow are the probabilities of the current node's offspring.    But every time that we choose a new child node, we actually shift down the tree, and "forget" the root node, out window is only N words wide, which translates to N levels deep into the tree.

You can easily see that if you are walking a Markov chain/tree like this, at any time the probability before the first word is 1, the probability after the first word is P(w1), after the second word = P(w2) || w1, etc. So, when processing the corpus you build a Markov tree ( := update the frequencies in the nodes), at the end of the ride you can estimate the probability of a given choice of word by freq(word) / SUM(freq(siblings)).  For a word 5-deep into the tree this is the **probability of the word, given the previous 4 words**.  If you want the N-gram probabilities, you want the **product of all the probabilities in the path** from the root to the last word.

Comment: BTW: my toy-project http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ used Markov chains (inherited from Megahal http://megahal.alioth.debian.org/ )

Comment: Four words was only an example, I want to find another like 2 or 3, or more, 5, 6, 7, until a defined number.

Comment: 2 or 3 can be obtained by aggregating, once you have the 4 component array. You can, of course use a larger window+array, but be prepared to get _very_ large histograms. Storing (and retrieving) a 10 dimensional array will be a major effort. Probably a tree would be optimal at some point (wakkerbot uses a 5-level / 5-gram tree with N-ary hashtables on tokennumber in every node) Most nodes are narrow, only the rootnode is full-width. Storing the tree in a recursive database-table seems possible and is scalable, but would probably perform bad, typically 100 ms / query.

Comment: This answer received much up votes, but I don't know about Markov chains and the by-product of Markov chains. I thank you answer, but can you add more explanation in the answer? Please.

Comment: The wikipedia article on marckov chains is very readable. Anyway, I'll amend my answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical use case for Markov chains. Estimate the Markov model from your textbase and find high probabilites in the transition table. Since these indicate probabilities that one word will follow another, phrases will show up as high transition probabilites.

By counting the number of times the phrase-start word showed up in the texts, you can also derive absolute numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small snippet that calculates all combinations/ngrams of a text for a given set of words. In order to work for larger datasets it uses the hash library, though it is probably still pretty slow...

```
require(hash)

get.ngrams <- function(text, target.words) {
  text <- tolower(text)
  split.text <- strsplit(text, "\\W+")[[1]]
  ngrams <- hash()
  current.ngram <- ""
  for(i in seq_along(split.text)) {
    word <- split.text[i]
    word_i <- i
    while(word %in% target.words) {
      if(current.ngram == "") {
        current.ngram <- word
      } else {
        current.ngram <- paste(current.ngram, word)
      }
      if(has.key(current.ngram, ngrams)) {
        ngrams[[current.ngram]] <- ngrams[[current.ngram]] + 1
      } else{
        ngrams[[current.ngram]] <- 1
      }
      word_i <- word_i + 1
      word <- split.text[word_i]
    }
    current.ngram <- ""
  }
  ngrams
}
```

So the following input ...

```
some.text <- "He states that he loves the United States of America,
 and I agree it is nice in the United States."
some.target.words <- c("united", "states", "of", "america")

usa.ngrams <- get.ngrams(some.text, some.target.words)
```

... would result in the following hash:

```
>usa.ngrams
<hash> containing 10 key-value pair(s).
  america : 1
  of : 1
  of america : 1
  states : 3
  states of : 1
  states of america : 1
  united : 2
  united states : 2
  united states of : 1
  united states of america : 1
```

Notice that this function is case insensitive and registers any permutation of the target words, e.g:

```
some.text <- "States of united America are states"
some.target.words <- c("united", "states", "of", "america")
usa.ngrams <- get.ngrams(some.text, some.target.words)
```

...results in:

```
>usa.ngrams
<hash> containing 10 key-value pair(s).
  america : 1
  of : 1
  of united : 1
  of united america : 1
  states : 2
  states of : 1
  states of united : 1
  states of united america : 1
  united : 1
  united america : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its of a help to you, but here is a little python program I wrote about a year ago that counts N-grams (well, only mono-, bi-, and trigrams). (It also calculates the entropy of each N-gram). I used it to count those N-grams in a large text.
[Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5482205/entropy.py)